# Help for font name

Tags: fonts

I have used the ClassicThesis model for my thesis, but it is asked to me to change the font.. Could you tell me the name of [this text-body](https://www.sciencemag.org/site/feature/contribinfo/prep/TeX_help/scifile.pdf) font?

Comment: looks like `\usepackage{times}` perhaps.

Comment: By looking at the font properties of the file, you'll learn that Times Roman, Times Roman Italic, Times Roman Bold, and Courier (for monospaced text) are used in the file. As per Steven Segletes's suggestion, load the `times` package to enable Times Roman as the main text font and Courier as the monospaced font. If you need a Times Roman-compatible math font, I suggest you load the `newtxmath` package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in comments.